# How can <*> accept functions in a context with a large number of parameters in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

The <*> function has the type Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a - > f b, but it can take the first argument of a function in a context with a large number of arguments (f (a - >b->c)).Yes, there is currying and yet why does haskell accept this?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, currying.

This works because there's no such thing as a function with multiple arguments in the first place. `A->B->C` is technically speaking the type of functions with *a single argument* of type `A`. The result of those functions happens to be again a function type, `B->C`, but the first `<*>` doesn't care about that. The *next* `<*>` may care about it and bind the `B` argument as well, but that's a separate step.

Answer (score 1):

`Yes, there is currying`

and that's quite literally all there is to it.

A function of type `a -> b -> c` is in fact of type `a -> (b -> c)` - the two are completely equivalent, because of currying.

So the signature of `<*>` is `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a - > f b`, as you say. But if `b` is also a function type, say `c -> d`, then this can be, as a specialisation:

```
Applicative f => f (a -> c -> d) -> f a - > f (c -> d)
```

and so on if it turns out that `d` above is in fact itself a function type.